# Can the type 3 SS be obtained using the ANOVA function or an adaptation that is readily available in Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

The default output for the ANOVA function is that of a type 1 Sum of Squares (SS) table. This is sufficient for a one-way ANOVA, however, when running an n-way ANOVA (with n greater than 1) and allowing for interactions to be tested the "accepted" method seems to be either type 2 or 3 SS. I have been unable to locate a method allowing the output of the type 3 SS from the ANOVA function and have confirmed using XLSTAT that the output from the ANOVA function in Mathematica is a type 1 SS. I can of course make use of XLSTAT for such analyses but would like to use Mathematica for all data analysis if possible.
Below is an example to showcase the effect of factor order on the type 1 SS for unbalanced data. The dataset shown below is copied from the ANOVA documentation page with the last entry removed to make the dataset unbalanced.

```
threewaydata = {{1, 1, 1, 50}, {1, 1, 1, 50}, {1, 1, 1, 54}, {1, 1, 2,
     40}, {1, 1, 2, 36}, {1, 1, 2, 40}, {1, 2, 1, 48}, {1, 2, 1, 
    48}, {1, 2, 1, 44}, {1, 2, 2, 14}, {1, 2, 2, 18}, {1, 2, 2, 
    14}, {2, 1, 1, 40}, {2, 1, 1, 36}, {2, 1, 1, 36}, {2, 1, 2, 
    18}, {2, 1, 2, 14}, {2, 1, 2, 18}, {2, 2, 1, 6}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2,
     2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 20}, {2, 2, 2, 16}};
```

The following code reorders the factors provided to the ANOVA function.

```
ANOVA[threewaydata[[All, {1, 2, 3, 4}]], {α, β, γ, All}, {α, β, γ}][[1]]
ANOVA[threewaydata[[All, {2, 1, 3, 4}]], {β, α, γ, All}, {β, α, γ}][[1]]
ANOVA[threewaydata[[All, {3, 1, 2, 4}]], {γ, α, β, All}, {γ, α, β}][[1]]
```

Below are the respective outputs. The p values for the factors and their interactions differ due to the order in which they are included (with the exception of the 3 way interaction as it is included last). This is not an issue when using a type 3 SS. For this reason I would like to know if the type 3 SS can be obtained either using the ANOVA function itself, or if there is another function capable of doing so.

[image: Input and output cells for the ANOVA analyses with reordered factors]

The type 3 SS obtained from XLSTAT is shown below (this is the desired output).
[image: XLSTAT output]
Below is the same analysis performed in Graphpad Prism. It appears to be an equivalent result to that of XLSTAT (with the factors in a different order and with less precision shown for the p-values)
[image: GraphpadPrism output]

Comment: Welcome to the community. [`FittedModel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FittedModel.html) (produced by [`LinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html)) have a property called `"SequentialSumOfSquares"`, and `"PartialSumOfSquares"` which is what you're looking for (based on my limited knowledge, it doesn't support `All`, and other statistics should be calculated manually).

Comment: Because not all software uses the same definition of Type III SS, please give the results from XLSTAT or SAS or R that you want from the data and model you provided.  As @BenIzd mentions `LinearModelFit` gives an option for obtaining `PartialSumOfSquares` which is what Type III SS are sometimes called.  However, this doesn't match what SAS gives for Type III SS.

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. I have updated my question to include outputs from both XLSTAT and Graphpad Prism for the type 3 SS. I will look into LinearModelFit to see if the output is equivalent to that of XLSTAT.

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  For whatever it's worth, those values for XLSTAT and Graphpad Prism match what SAS gives.

Comment: Apologies for not doing so initially-first question so learning how best to format questions here. From what I understand the definition of type 3 SS is universal so I would expect them to be equivalent. The difference seems to be that different software packages (or coding environments) seem to prefer type 2 or type 3 SS. Type 1 SS seems to be used less often as it emphasizes the factor(s) listed first (hence the order of the factors changes the result.

Comment: "I understand the definition of type 3 SS is universal."  Not exactly.  See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.00545.pdf.

Comment: @JimB Thank you very much for linking that; quite an interesting read and explains why I was having difficulty finding explicit formulae to calculate the type 3 SS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I'll just tackle the problem when the number of levels is just 2 for each of the categorical variables.

The `PartialSumOfSquares` property of `LinearModelFit` will provide the Type III sum of squares that R, SAS, XLSTAT, and GraphPad Prism but (so far) only when the categorical variables are coded in a specific way.  And that way is Deviation Coding (see https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#DEVIATION).

For this case that means recoding the 1's and 2's to 1's and -1's.

```
threewaydata = {{1, 1, 1, 50}, {1, 1, 1, 50}, {1, 1, 1, 54}, {1, 1, 2, 40}, 
  {1, 1, 2, 36}, {1, 1, 2, 40}, {1, 2, 1, 48}, {1, 2, 1, 48}, {1, 2, 1, 44},
  {1, 2, 2, 14}, {1, 2, 2, 18}, {1, 2, 2, 14}, {2, 1, 1, 40}, {2, 1, 1, 36},
  {2, 1, 1, 36}, {2, 1, 2, 18}, {2, 1, 2, 14}, {2, 1, 2, 18}, {2, 2, 1, 6},
  {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 20}, {2, 2, 2, 16}};

(* Convert 2's to -1'2 *)
data = threewaydata;
data[[All, 1]] = -2 data[[All, 1]] + 3;
data[[All, 2]] = -2 data[[All, 2]] + 3;
data[[All, 3]] = -2 data[[All, 3]] + 3;
lmf = LinearModelFit[data, {α, β, γ, α β, α γ, β γ, α β γ}, {α, β, γ}]
(* Type I sums of squares - default *)
lmf["ANOVATable"]
```

[image: Type I sums of squares]

```
(* Type III sums of squares *)
lmf["PartialSumOfSquares"]
(* {2074.51, 1298.98, 882.353, 7.68627, 509.647, 98.0392, 1029.18} *)
```

These match with R, SAS, XLSTAT, and GraphPad Prism.

Comment: And an editorial:  *Mathematica* is great but it has only a relatively primitive set of features for `LinearModelFit`.  For example, there is no automatic way to select the type of sum of squares (I, II, III, or IV), as there is only a single error term allowed (i.e., mixed models are not implemented), and no nice way to produce contrasts or linear combinations of parameters.  All of those features can be programmed with *Mathematica* commands but that limits the number of folks able to do that correctly - even for those who know the statistical background.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have marked it as the solution.

Comment: Very instructive. Are you writing Mathematica code for mixed models etc? +1 :) of course

Comment: @ubpdqn. No way!  That functionality is far superior in R and SAS.

Comment: @JimB agree different tools for different purposes. My R is rudimentary and rusty and I haven’t used RLink. Look forward to continuing to learn from answers…and thank you for supportive comment on meta post.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation page [ANOVA/tutorial/ANOVA](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ANOVA/tutorial/ANOVA.html) gives the following example:

```
<<ANOVA`

threewaydata = {{1, 1, 1, 50}, {1, 1, 1, 50}, {1, 1, 1, 54}, {1, 1, 2,
     40}, {1, 1, 2, 36}, {1, 1, 2, 40}, {1, 2, 1, 48}, {1, 2, 1, 
    48}, {1, 2, 1, 44}, {1, 2, 2, 14}, {1, 2, 2, 18}, {1, 2, 2, 
    14}, {2, 1, 1, 40}, {2, 1, 1, 36}, {2, 1, 1, 36}, {2, 1, 2, 
    18}, {2, 1, 2, 14}, {2, 1, 2, 18}, {2, 2, 1, 6}, {2, 2, 1, 2}, {2,
     2, 1, 2}, {2, 2, 2, 20}, {2, 2, 2, 16}, {2, 2, 2, 20}};

ANOVA[threewaydata, {α, β, γ, α β, α γ, β γ}, {α, β, γ}]
```

and so it seems that all interactions could be determined with addition of a three-way product:

```
ANOVA[threewaydata, {α, β, γ, α β, α γ, β γ, α β γ}, {α, β, γ}]
```

This tutorial demonstrates a lot of options which can be employed to get you to the specific formula that you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I had previously looked into the documentation package you linked in your answer. My query focuses on the following statement quoted from the documentation: " All results are given as type I sums of squares". This means the order of the factors will affect the resulting p-values (with the exception of the final factor/interactions being added). For this reason type 3 SS is generally used, as it is not sequential: the order of the factors does change the resulting statistic or p-value. I will edit my question to better showcase this.